# Spring/Hibernate changes needed to be done when porting an application developed from a 32-bit machine to a 64-bit machine

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'd like to ask the following questions:

1. Are there specific configuration settings (for Spring/Hibernate) needed to be done when porting an application developed from a 32-bit OS to 64-bit OS?
2. Can all the libraries be used from the 32-bit to 64-bit? Or, do I have to look for 64-bit equivalent of these libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've developed code using pure java an haven't used native libraries, then you can be rest assured that your programs are (os) architecture independent i.e. they will work on either 32-bit or 64-bit OSes

Comment: thanks..hmm, how can I know that these libraries are native or not?

Comment: if your libraries just consist of 'jar' files without any .so, .dll or any other os dependent files, then you should be fine.

Comment: you might want to 'accept' this answer if you think it addressed your question appropriately

Comment: hello again...i'd like to know if you have online documents/known sites/links about this information? I'm really interested to know where to find these stuffs....

Comment: to be honest, the fact that Spring and Hibernate do not have downloads for different operating system and architectures reassures me that you wont have problems while porting your app.